# Laravel sanctum 401 Unauthorized

Tags: laravel, api

I'm trying to set-up Laravel authentication using sanctum. I'm able to create a successful login function, which returns a token (bearer), but once that bearer is added to a next request using postman, a 401 unauthorized is received, and I cannot figure out why. I'm running the setup using XAMPP (127.0.0.1:8000).

Config/auth contains the following guards

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users'
    ]
],
```

The config/sanctum guard is set to api.

I've added (and tested with) the following variables in the .env file;

```
SESSION_DOMAIN='localhost'
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS='localhost:8000'
```

Lastly, routes are set as follows;

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::apiResource('friends', FriendsController::class);
});
```

I'm now unsure what the issue could possibly be.

Comment: you need to add bearer token to access the routes protected by scantum middle ware ....
request from frontend should be like this reffer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72231664/15177375

Comment: Yes, I'm aware and already do so. So unfortunatly that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using axios make sure to set it to send the cookies

```
import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
window.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

also make sure to see the config/cors.php

```
<?php
return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
];
```

finally add the domains to your .env file , SPA location in app url , backend in sanctum stateful domains

```
APP_URL=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8000
```

and most importantly don't forget to run this to load the new .env

```
php artisan config:cache
```